# Where is the bounty button?

Tags: support, bounties

I do not see any bounty button. I've checked the FAQ and related questions, but I guess nobody has been so lame to ask this question so far.

I'm a newbie to this site and my situation is like this:

- my reputation is 51
- the question age says 3 days

Are there any other requirements I have to meet to offer bounty for my question, that are not mentioned in FAQ? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> my reputation is 51

You need 75 rep to start a bounty. See the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/):

> If:
>
> - you have at least 75 reputation
> - your question is at least two days old

The blog also mentions that your question may not already have an accepted answer, but that has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067), you need 75 reputation in order to start a bounty.

> You must have at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and at least as much reputation as the bounty amount.
>
> The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded.